# How to Initialize multiple TextViews neatly?

Tags: java, android, view, textview, initialization

I'd like to make this code more concise but I want to keep each TextViews reference/name.

```
    airportCodeText1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.airportCode1);
    airportCodeText2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.airportCode2);
    airportText1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.airport1);
    airportText2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.airport2);
    departureTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.departureTime);
    arrivalTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.arrivalTime);
    flightNunberText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.flightNoText);
    desk = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.desk);
    gate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.gate);
    flightNumberTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.flightNoTitle);
    deskTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.deskTitle);
    gateTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.gateTitle);
```

Comment: Is this is neat now? What your are asking about?

Comment: Let's say I had 100 of these I'd be drowning my class in text and it would take a very long time. If I didn't need the references I'd make an array within a for loop.

I'm looking for a more concise way of initialization for large numbers of TextViews.

Comment: May I just ask, why on earth would you have 100!?

Comment: Don't feel like we are judging you, it may just help us think of a solution if you tell us why you need 100 of them and what you plan to do with them after is all :)

Comment: Take a look at butterknife: https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife and Android Annotations: https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations

Comment: @Losin'Me I don't really need 100 I'm just a bit OCD about having concise code rather than a dozen lines doing pretty much the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably just use a method to declare the R.id's for the different variables you wish to initialize. So you should firstly declare the method in the main body then use the method to initialize each findViewById section

I'd appreciate an upvote for this but if this solution doesn't suit your needs then there are other ways including listviews to accomplish the same task.

```
Public class yourclassname extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

Text View airportCodeText1, airportCodeText2, airporttext1, airporttext2, departureTime, arrivalTime, flightNumberText, desk, gate, flightNumberTitle, deskTitle, gateTitle;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);
        Initializer();
       }

 private void initializer() {
        airportCodeText1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.airportCode1);
        //Repeat for each TextView 
        //I didnt wanna do the whole code for you.

       }
```

Comment: That seems to be the most staightforward and simple way to do it. And you get to see one of the method's primary usage, to reduce repetition.

Comment: Yeah  I mean there are other ways around the same solution but this is probably the least complex use of basic java without the introduction of complex libraries and changes. I can try modify my second solution to suit the answer but that may take some time